# Group dictionary in a list of dictionaries by the first letter of a Value

Tags: python

I'm having a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
  [{
    'Host-id': 'W000644',
    'Email': 'Hotmail',
    'Color': 'red',
    'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
    'Host-id': 'W000955',
    'Email': 'Hotmail',
    'Color': 'red',
    'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
    'Host-id': 'K000003',
    'Email': 'Gmail',
    'Color': 'green',
    'Timestamp': '15-11-2021'
    },
    'Host-id': 'G000004',
    'Email': 'Colemail',
    'Color': 'blue',
    'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'
    },
    {
    'Host-id': 'S000002',
    'Email': 'Gmail',
    'Color': 'blue',
    'Timestamp': '22-10-2021'
    },
    {
    'Host-id': 'G000003',
    'Email': 'spam',
    'Color': 'red',
    'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'
    }]
```

I want to group it, using the first letter of the 'Host-Id' Value (like 'W' for Water or 'G' for Gas) so it looks finally like this:

```
  {
    "Water": [
          {
         'Host-id': 'W000644',
         'Email': 'Hotmail',
         'Color': 'red',
         'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
         },
         {
         'Host-id': 'W000955',
         'Email': 'Hotmail',
         'Color': 'red',
         'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
         }
   ],

   "Gas":[
        {
        'Host-id': 'G000004',
        'Email': 'Colemail',
        'Color': 'blue',
        'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'
        }, 
        {
        'Host-id': 'G000003',
        'Email': 'spam',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'
       } 
     ]
   }
```

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start. I have tried it with a loop but it looks overly complex and didnt yield the results I wanted. Could anyone please point me into the right direction?

Thank you in advance

A

Comment: What is the link between `water` and `Gas` and your original list?

Comment: you could try with a for loop and 2 secondary lists and check if "Host-id" value starts with G or W and add the dict to the correct list

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle Looks like the `W` and `G` at the beginning of the `Host-id` corresponds to Water and Gas.

Comment: Use a dictionary like `{'W': 'Water', 'G': 'Gas'}` to translate the first letter of the Host-id to the corresponding key in the result dictionary.

Comment: also loops work pretty good here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [PyFunctional](https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional) library for your task. It could be done without loops like this

```
from functional import seq

lst = [
    {
        'Host-id': 'W000644',
        'Email': 'Hotmail',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'W000955',
        'Email': 'Hotmail',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'G000004',
        'Email': 'Colemail',
        'Color': 'blue',
        'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'G000003',
        'Email': 'spam',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'
    }
]

KEY_MAP = {
    "W": "Water",
    "G": "Gas",
}

s = seq(lst)
res = s.group_by(lambda x: KEY_MAP[x['Host-id'][0]])
print(res.to_dict())
```

Output

```
{
    'Water': [
        {'Host-id': 'W000644', 'Email': 'Hotmail', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'},
        {'Host-id': 'W000955', 'Email': 'Hotmail', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'}
    ],
    'Gas': [
        {'Host-id': 'G000004', 'Email': 'Colemail', 'Color': 'blue', 'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'},
        {'Host-id': 'G000003', 'Email': 'spam', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: merci @eugenij super solution. didnt know this module. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my dummy approach without using any external modules (and you shouldn't unless needed either)...,

```py
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    {
        'Host-id': 'W000644',
        'Email': 'Hotmail',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'W000955',
        'Email': 'Hotmail',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'G000004',
        'Email': 'Colemail',
        'Color': 'blue',
        'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'
    },
    {
        'Host-id': 'G000003',
        'Email': 'spam',
        'Color': 'red',
        'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'
    }
]

KEY_MAP = {
    "W": "Water",
    "G": "Gas",
}


resp = defaultdict(list)

"""
We are grouping our items on the first character of the "Host-id" (as you have mentioned) by passing a lambda to the `key` arg of the groupby. 

And then you can just loop over the group and append back the results.

The advantage of using this is now, I don't have to worry about how many different first characters etc are possible as we have not hardcoded anything. 

(Except them being present in the KEY_MAP as well)
"""

for key, group in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: KEY_MAP.get(x["Host-id"][0])):
    for thing in group:
        resp[key].append(thing)

print(resp)
```

Output

```py
{
    'Water': [
        {'Host-id': 'W000644', 'Email': 'Hotmail', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'},
        {'Host-id': 'W000955', 'Email': 'Hotmail', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-10-2021'}
    ],
    'Gas': [
        {'Host-id': 'G000004', 'Email': 'Colemail', 'Color': 'blue', 'Timestamp': '14-11-2021'},
        {'Host-id': 'G000003', 'Email': 'spam', 'Color': 'red', 'Timestamp': '12-11-2021'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aditya , this is also a very nice solution ;)

Comment: Glad that's its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```py
items = [] # list of dictionaries
gas = []
water = []

for d in items:
    if d["host-id"][0] == "W":
        water.append(d)
    elif d["host-id"][0] == "G":
        gas.append(d)

print(gas)
print(water)
```

And then you can save those lists in a dictionary:

```py
outDict = {"gas" : gas, "water" : water}
```

Comment: this will work when you have only 2 chars, what would you do when you don't know how many different chars are possible? In such scenarios, we should prefer writing snips that can work "generically" maybe as far as possible.